# Determining if a location is within a polygon in Google Earth?

Tags: python, google-maps, csv, kml, google-earth

So I have a `.csv` file with about `50,000` coordinate entries, and a `.kml` file specifying around **40 polygons**.

What is the best way for me to determine which of these points lie within the polygons?

I have attempted writing a `python script` to perform a ray tracing algorithm to determine this point by point, but it takes upwards of 5 minutes and I need to run this many times. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Search in the Standard Template Libraries (C++, Java) for the algorithms of Lucas Simonson.  I think they were accepted in 2010.  He did some wonderful work on basic polygon operations, reducing the order of complexity.  Inclusion of a point in a polygon set was one of those.